# Dubai Transit with separate different tickets with Afghan Passport

Tags: air-travel, transit, dubai, dxb, afghan-citizens

I am travelling with an Afghan passport and Canadian permanent resident card from Vancouver (YVR) to Kabul (KBL) via London (LHR) and Dubai (DXB) with two separate ticket bookings. The first one is with British Airways from YVR-LHR-DXB and the second from DXB-KBL is with Emirates.

I will arrive in Dubai T1 at 7:30 a.m. and my next flight DXB-KBL with Emirates leaves from Terminal 3 at 9:55 a.m. on the very same day with only 2.5 hours layover in Dubai.

I am carrying just my hand luggage.

I do not have Dubai transit visa, so can I just walk from T1 To T3 and get on board to my next flight with Emirates without the Dubai transit visa or without going through any immigration/custom clearance?

Answer (score 7):

At Dubai airport, because you only have hand luggage, you **can** transit between terminal 1 and 3 without clearing immigration, as they are connected through the transit corridor.

However, since you have two separate bookings, you'll likely be denied boarding at YVR. Many check-in clerks will argue that Dubai is your final destination, and thus require the relevant entry documentation for the UAE.

My advice, go to the airport **immediately**, show the check-in clerks your onward flight confirmation to Kabul, explain that you'll only have hand luggage, and ask if they will let you board without a UAE visa. If they say yes, insist that they write you a confirmation that you can take with you to show staff at the gate if necessary.

If they insist you need a UAE visa, try contacting them again later, as different agents may say different things. If at least three different agents all keep insisting you need a UAE visa, you can get one [online](http://www.ednrd.ae/)

**Do NOT, under any circumstances**, let them play their standard card: "we don't know, it's not our responsibility, ask the embassy". They do that all the time, but on the day of travel, suddenly they know exactly whether to let you board, and won't change their mind even if you call the embassy in front of them.

What they won't tell you is that they rely on a database called Timatic, which says (regarding Dubai):

> Visa required, except for holders of confirmed onward tickets for a max. transit time of 24 hours

However, like I said check-in clerks often interpret this as "holders of confirmed onward tickets **in the same booking**"¨

Like I said, clear this up **immediately**.

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt and informative reply Crazydre. I will try my best to take care of all the necessary steps before travelling. Thank you again! :)